# Calling the replaceCurrentItem(with:) method not working after an error occurs on AirPlay

Tags: ios, avfoundation, http-live-streaming, airplay

My problem is quite complex, so I am going to describe it in detail below ;-)

I am developing a playback app that makes use of HLS streaming. One of the requirements I have to meet is that my app should react to the HTTP response headers. As there is no API to get this information, I applied the solution described here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/31646?answerId=207001022#207001022  – I am using a proxy server to extract the headers from the response.

The problem happens when a user wants to stream video on an external device via AirPlay. Since the proxy server runs only on a mobile device, any HTTP request fails on the external device due to an incorrect URL (e.g `http://127.0.0.1:58244/theRestOfUrl/playlist.m3u8`). In this case, I detect when the AirPlay connection is initiated (via the Notification Center mechanism), and then change `AVPlayerItem` by calling the `replaceCurrentItem(with:)` method. The new item contains a correct URL, without the proxy server address added. Everything works fine on AirPlay 2, but unfortunately not on older AirPlay – the player on the external device displays an activity indicator for a moment and after a while the connection is being interrupted. As a workaround, I tried to set `nil` on `AVPlayer` and create a new instance of it, but this does not work either.

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Comment: I filed a bug report in Feedback Assistant. The issue has been resolved in the latest update :)